# Use Both Camera And Gallery Option in Webview On <input type="file">

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an android app with webView.In Which user can upload photos via **openFileChooser()** Method  but the problem is that there is either gallery option used or camera activity Call. How can I achieve the solution to show a dialog for choose an image via gallery or camera in webView . How to Achieeve This Thanks In advance.